# How do I get Joomla module title in custom fields?

Tags: joomla

I am creating a custom field in Joomla. I have this code:

```
class JFormFieldEmbed extends JFormField {
    protected $type = 'Embed';
    public function getInput() {
        $out='';
        $out.='<pre>'.print_r($this->form,true).'</pre>';
        return $out;
    }
}
```

I see in the output $form->data that contains the title but is a protected object.

How do I get Joomla module title in custom fields?

UPDATE:

By now my solution with JavaScript:

```
class JFormFieldEmbed extends JFormField {
    protected $type = 'Embed';
    public function getInput() {
        $script1=htmlentities('<script type="text/javascript" src="'.JURI::root().'modules/mod_mydodule/js/script.js" data-title="');
        $script2=htmlentities('"></script>');
return<<<EOD
<div id="embedmymodule"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $("#embedmymodule").html('$script1'+encodeURIComponent( $('[name=\"jform[title]\"]').val() )+'$script2');
    });
</script>
EOD;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the source files of Joomla:

```
echo $this->form->getValue('title');
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will output the module title:

```
$module->title
```